# Post serialized to xml object to mvc action

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

i have 2 projects.
First project send to 2-nd via http-post requests, as serialized to XML class instances.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<UserId>test user</UserId>
...
```

How can i recieve it in action of 2-nd project?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyObject id)
{ ...
```

or like string, and deserialize after?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to refactor this to JSON POST call. But yes, you can send xml data as string and deserealize it on server.

Comment: Unfortunately, ActionResult Index(string id) returns null.
Any ideas?

Comment: StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
            x.Serialize(writer, lo);

            if (writer != null)
            {
                byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
........

Send via HttpWebRequest

Comment: I've never implemented call this way but I suppose you shall construct post data the way your byte array is associated with id parameter. 

May be this article will be usefull:
http://www.jigar.net/howdoi/viewhtmlcontent106.aspx

Try to use WCF contract-based communication instead of creating post call by hands.